# Import css file as a block-level import using less

Tags: less

Is there a way to nest the rules of a .css file under a selector by using `@import` like you can when importing a .less file?

---

If you have a file, "x.less"

```
#x {
    color: #000;
}
```

and file "main.less"

```
.scope {
    @import "x.less";
}
```

compiling "main.less" results in

```
.scope #x {
  color: #000;
}
```

---

However, if you have
"y.css"

```
#y {
    color: #111;
}
```

and change "main.less" to

```
.scope {
    @import "y.css";
}
```

compiling "main.less" results in

```
.scope {
  @import "y.css";
}
```

---

And if you have 
"z.css"

```
#z {
    color: #222;
}
```

and change "main.less" to

```
.scope {
    @import (inline) "z.css";
}
```

compiling "main.less" results in

```
.scope {
  #z {
  color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(inline)` just injects the imported file "as-is" w/o parsing it, so the result of such import inside a ruleset is undefined (invalid CSS like in your example).
To get what you need use [`(less)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-less) option, e.g.:

```
.scope {
    @import (less) "z.css";
}
```