# Inject css content from absolute external url using LESS

Tags: css, less

I need to include css from external recourse into my result css. I use LESS preprocessor.

Is there the way to do this? For example,

```
.wrapper {
  @import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/styles/atelier-seaside.light.min.css';
}
```

But that's not working for me. I get the same css:

```
.wrapper {
  @import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/styles/atelier-seaside.light.min.css';
}
```

I want it to be:

```
.wrapper .hljs-comment {
  color: #687d68;
}
.wrapper .hljs-variable,
.wrapper .hljs-attribute,
/* etc. */
```

Comment: you have paste the same code?

Comment: @AndrésTalavera If I understand you right, yes the output is the same as the input, you can try it here http://less2css.org/ and that's a problem..

Comment: See [Import Options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Does less.js support inlining an import with an absolute URL? I had assumed no, because it would have to fetch it via a HTTP request, which has pretty severe performance implications. I'm curious, since I'm currently one of the maintainers of dotless and I'm looking at bringing dotless to feature parity with less.js.

Comment: @Rytmis Yes, it allows inlining of external imports. Sure, it kills compilation performance but it's nothing but EPTH to such code writers :).

Comment: @seven-phases-max that's good news :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max so what option to use? I don't see any mentions of "external" or "absolute" in the docs..

Comment: @starikovs `@import (inline)`, I'd wager. CSS imports are left as `@import` directives unless otherwise specified.

Comment: No, namespace/ruleset nested imports shoud be `(less`) not `(inline)`, for more details why see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29760625/2712740.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I was just about to correct myself. I was only concentrating on inlining, not namespacing. I actually implemented namespaced imports in Dotless recently, so I should know, but that doesn't always translate to the correct first answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS files are imported by leaving the @import directive as-is. If you want a CSS file to be treated as a LESS file (that is, inlined and namespaced) you should use `@import (less)`:

```
.wrapper {
  @import (less) 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/styles/atelier-seaside.light.min.css';
}
```

You should be aware that the file will be downloaded every time the less file gets compiled, so compilation performance is less than optimal.